# Insert arithmetic series in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm making a budgeting for renting equipment at a shop. Their pricing is as follow.

Day 1 costs 40

Day 2 costs day1+day1/2

Day 3 costs day2+day1/2

etc.

I want to put this in excel but I have no idea how to do it.

On each row I have a product with the first day cost, the amount of days I want to rent it and the total price.

Anyone got ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out after taking a quick look in my statistics book:

a_n = a_1+(n-1)*d where d is the arithmetic difference

Comment: You should post that as an answer and mark it as accepted, unless you need anything additional.

Comment: @DavidVandenbos I can't post it yet as an answer. I will tomorrow ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after taking a quick look in my statistics book:

a_n = a_1+(n-1)*d where d is the arithmetic difference

I just used this in my grand total cell and i got it to work